# Get URL of image on firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mobile

How can i get the url of an image on my firebase storage and then put it on my real-time database.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link [-https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url](http://-https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url)

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
        Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
        generatedFilePath = downloadUri.toString(); /// The string(file link) that you need
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: `Error: cannot resolve method getDownloadUrl() in StorageMetadata`. Please help me.

Comment: `taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getStorage().getDownloadUrl();` or check out with this also `taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();`

Comment: Now is say when the required type is `Task<Uri>` and not `Uri`, but if I set the type to `Task<Uri>` the error is gone. Also what type is the variable `generatedFilePath`??